# How to add obj to to state in my example Redux React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem with adding obj to my arr in redux store.

I want to check if some element in my arr have the same id with payload id - I don't want to push, if not push the object to array.

The initial state of the array - [] (empty)

MY REDUCER CODE:

```
case "UNSHIFT_COUNTRY": {
      console.log("P", payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedCountries: [
          ...state.selectedCountries,
          state.selectedCountries.forEach(item => {
            if (item.id !== payload.id) {
              state.selectedCountries.unshift(payload);
            }
          })
        ]
      };
    }
```

PAYLOAD IS AN OBJECT

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` to check if your array has an object with the same `id`:

```
case "UNSHIFT_COUNTRY": {
  const found = state.selectedCountries.find(country => country.id === payload.id);

  return found ? state : {
    ...state,
    selectedCountries: [...state.selectedCountries, payload]
  };
}
```